# How to develop the next best alternative to chrome extension in android

Tags: android

I have built a chrome extension that works fine. I know I can't deploy it to android. So I would have to build an app. The app may or may not have anything to do with chrome; I don't know. This isn't a chrome extension question.

But as to the integration between the app and the on-board browser, I see the android api doesn't have any functionality for browser or web integration? Is that correct?

I'm just making sure because building an app that is essentially it's own proprietary browser, just to get my functionality onto android, is not really something I think a lot of people would download. I'm looking for a more integrated way than that. Is there one?

For those who say impossible, I know for a fact there is an app which added a context menu inside chrome on android but I have no idea how they did that or what other integration is possible. It was a webpage pdf converter. Upon clicking that menu it converted the webpage to pdf, and opened the pdf in the app.

Comment: "I see the android api doesn't have any functionality for browser or web integration? Is that correct?" -- um, well, Android is an OS. Browsers are apps. Windows does not have "browser or web integration" for Chrome, Firefox, etc. Android does not have "browser or web integration" for Chrome, Firefox, etc. In all of those cases, either the app on that OS offers an API, or it does not. I am not quite certain what you are expecting Android itself to do for you here.

Comment: @CommonsWare, ok, does Chrome on Android have any api?